# Total size of multiple Bit(1) fields in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

What are the size implications of storing many booleans in one Postgres table? I'd like to be able to filter on these fields without doing bit manipulation, so I want them to be separate fields.

I found a [related question about SQL Server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/243288/multiple-bit-datatype-columns-in-the-same-table), and the answer was that 8 bit fields indeed only take 1 byte of space (nullability aside). However, the PostgreSQL documentation says:

> Writing bit without a length is equivalent to bit(1)

and:

> A bit string value requires 1 byte for each group of 8 bits, plus 5 or 8 bytes overhead depending on the length of the string

Does this mean a table with 8 separate BIT columns will take up 40 or more bytes per row? Or will it also only take a single byte for all 8?

```
CREATE TABLE SomeBits (
    b1 BIT,
    b2 BIT,
    b3 BIT,
    b4 BIT,
    b5 BIT,
    b6 BIT,
    b7 BIT,
    b8 BIT
)
```

Comment: A `bit` is not a `boolean` - what is it exactly you are trying to store? A bit or a boolean?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name A bit(1) is conceptually equivalent to a Boolean. They are isomorphic, etc. Why do you say they're not?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You're saying they are distinct data types in Postgres; that makes sense. Thank you for that comment -- I was not aware of the `BOOLEAN` data type.

Comment: In SQL those are two different things. The result of `6 > 5` is a boolean expression, not a "bit"

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9993552/939860

Answer (score 3):

Using the technique from [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48929358/1362272), I created a table with 8 BIT(1) columns and checked its size. It was indeed 48 bytes.

In a comment, a_horse_with_no_name pointed out that PostgreSQL has explicit support for the BOOLEAN data type, which is better for storing booleans than BIT(1). A table with 8 BOOLEANS appears to take 8 bytes per row, which is a little better at least.

Testing table sizes:

```
CREATE TABLE SomeBools (
    b1 BOOLEAN,
    b2 BOOLEAN,
    b3 BOOLEAN,
    b4 BOOLEAN,
    b5 BOOLEAN,
    b6 BOOLEAN,
    b7 BOOLEAN,
    b8 BOOLEAN
);

INSERT INTO SomeBools(b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8)
VALUES (TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE);

SELECT pg_column_size(SomeBools) - 24 from SomeBools;
```

> 8

```
CREATE TABLE SomeBits (
    b1 BIT,
    b2 BIT,
    b3 BIT,
    b4 BIT,
    b5 BIT,
    b6 BIT,
    b7 BIT,
    b8 BIT
);

INSERT INTO SomeBits(b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8)
VALUES (B'0', B'0', B'1', B'1', B'0', B'1', B'0', B'1');

SELECT pg_column_size(SomeBits) - 24 from SomeBits;
```

> 48

Comment: Another option is to use a single column with `bit(8)`  which is slightly smaller than 8 booleans. But it might be more complicated to work with e.g. you can just write `where b4` but you need to use some bit operators to extract the one bit you are after.